# QVector, QList etc.. why index is int and not size_t

Tags: c++, qt, indexing

I'm using some Qt container, like `QList` and `QVector`, and I've noticed that the index for accessing data is defined as `int` instead that `size_t`. I've always seen `size_t` in STL, Boost and other containers, so I'd like to know why Qt does not use it. Is there some meaning for negative numbers regarding these containers?

Comment: I believe that the answer to the duplicated question is questionable at best... The comment from The Paramagnetic Croissant in the other question is probably a better answer. This is one of the many annoying poor design decision in qt. For the record, try to not learn from Qt and do  use signed and unsigned properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an arbitrary choice. The negative numbers are not valid indices when used to access elements. Sometimes they may have special meaning when used for methods other than direct element access.

Normally it doesn't matter that you can only access 2 billion items instead of 4 billion. If you're anywhere near that number of items, you should be using something else for your container anyway.

Comment: `int` is only guaranteed to be at least 16k, not 2 billion. Besides that, `size_t` is not limited to 4 billion on most current desktop computers - and even phones are starting to enter the 64 bit era!

Comment: @gha.st:  I don't think Qt is built on any platform that uses a 16 bit `int`.

Comment: @gha.st It doesn't matter what `int` is guaranteed to be, since Qt supports a finite number of platforms, and none of them have 16 bit ints. It's a done deal, no "ifs" or "buts" about it. Moreover, `Qt` will simply not work on anything with 16 bit ints. It'll limp along at best, with lots of broken functionality. I've tried it once and it wasn't pretty. I had to do a grep replace of `int` with `int32_t` to get it working. Again, Qt's (and C++'s) collections make little sense with such large item counts, so `int` is, from a practical point of view, perfectly adequate.

Comment: It's not only about 2^32 vs 2^31. Checking if an `unsigned` is a valid index is easy ( `i < size()` vs  `i >=0 && i < size()`).  Moreover, using `int` where `unsigned` is the logically correct choice often hides subtle bugs, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion (unless you use `signed int` everywhere in your application).
I disagree that `Qt's (and C++'s) collections make little sense with such large item counts,`, I can see use cases for a 4Gb `QByteArray` (won't use QByteArray because it's too hard to prevent COW, but it works properly with the STL containers).

Comment: I have used STL containers with significantly more than 4 GB for previous projects - and they work just fine. And explaining away a bad design choice of a multi-platform toolkit by saying that it is not *that* multi-platform is really funny ;D

Comment: In my opinion it matters from a logical point of view. If I want to access some data it's natural for me to use an unsigned index because in an array negative index have not meaning (ok, they can represent indices from the end of the array, like Mathematica, but this is not the case). Int is more error prone, and I don't agree to use negative indices as return value when some error occurs. There are better error handling methods in C++. Due to this I wanted to know if there was some reason for this choiche that I don't understand.

Comment: @gha.st: why is it funny that Qt doesn't target platforms that can't reasonably support its functionality? It seems like that would be a complete waste of time and effort.